# get youtube video duration in specific format

Tags: php, time, youtube-api

I'm using youtube version 3 api to get video data, I got the duration of video in `ISO 8601` format, I tried to convert it to `HH:MM:II` using the following code

```
<?php
$duration = 'PT3M42S';

$time = strtotime($duration);

$durationConverted = time('HH : MM : II', $duration);
echo $durationConverted;

?>
```

but the result = 1431647650 , I want `PT3M42S` converted to something like this `00:03:42` or `03:42`

Comment: Try switching `time('HH : MM : II', $duration);` to `date('HH : MM : II', $duration);`.  See [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [time()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php).  May not work, as that's for a timestamp rather than a duration.

Comment: I changed it to date, and this is the result =  1919 : DecDec : 00 @adamdc78

Comment: See this: https://gist.github.com/w0rldart/9e10aedd1ee55fc4bc74  (Convert `ISO8601` to `Secounds`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$duration = new DateInterval('PT3M42S');
echo $duration->format('%H:%I:%S');
```

00:03:42

http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

Comment: Call to undefined function DateInterval()

Comment: Did you omit the `new` keyword?

Comment: DateInterval requires PHP 5.3 or later